# Cakephp 2.0 Jquery works in layout but not in view, or vice versa

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a JQuery menu in my layout, and JQuery items inside of my view. I have jquery-1.7.js added in the layout with this line:
echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery-1.7.js', 'modal/lib/prototype.js', 'modal/lib/scriptaculous.js?load=builder,effects', 'modal/modalbox.js'));

After I do this, the menu works fine. However the jquery items in my View do not work.

If I redeclare jquery-1.7 inside my view (with a similar line), the jquery in my view works, but not in my layout.

How can I make it so both of these work? I tried exploring the beforLayout function of cakephp but I cant find any usage examples. Am I atleast on the right track?

Comment: Turns out the issue was not to do with loading the libraries. It had to do with loading jQuery and Prototype. I used jQuery.noConflict and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was not to do with loading the libraries. It had to do with loading jQuery and Prototype. I used jQuery.noConflict and it works now.